# Проблема обмена заказами сайта с 1с

Tags: php, 1с

возникла проблема, которую никак немогу понять каким образом решить. Проблема заключается в том что из сайта PHP заказы Имена которых НЕ СОВПАДАЕТ с именами товаров внутри 1с - успешно выгружаются, а если внутри заказа из сайта имеется Товар имя которого СОВПАДАЕТ с именем товара внутри 1с - заказы не выгружаются в разделе Заказы клиентов 1с

Comment: Покажите хотя бы как запрос построен на основе которого берутся данные из 1С.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете стандартный модуль обмена, то скорее всего дело в настройках. Как вы создали товары на сайте? Выгружали их из 1С тем же модулем обмена? Тогда у них должен быть external_id и он должен совпадать с идентификатором товара в 1С.